# How to get a report, in Google Analytics, about where the most engaged new users come from (acquisition)?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to get a report that represents, for each source of acquisition, the percentage of the new users who visited at least X pages during their first session (or, alternatively, stay on the site for at least X minutes on their first session). Something like:

Google organic search: 10%
Google ads: 12%
Quora: 20%
.....

what's the easiest way to get that?

I would also like to see past data and I think this excludes the use of goals (goals data is registered starting from the moment you create the gaol).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option on the fly: go to Audience > Behavior > Engagement. This will allow you to toggle between "session duration" (how long they stayed on the site) and "page depth" (how many pages they viewed). From there, you can "add segment" for all your top sources to compare them.

For a full-fledged report, instead go to Customization > Custom Reports. For metric groups add "avg. session duration" and "pages/session" and for dimension drilldowns add "source/medium" (or source, or however you want to view the referral sites). You can then apply the "new users" filter to single them out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First solution: I don't get the "source/medium".

Second solution: maybe I am missing something but I don't see any "new users" option in the filters menu.

Comment: You might have to create the filter yourself if it doesn't come standard.

Comment: Got it, the filter is: "user type", the value "new visitor".
Thanks!